# Android Bluetooth InputStream.read() Keeps Stalling

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm using an InputStream to read data from my Arduino via bluetooth. I am using a separate thread to do this so as it does not block the UI thread. This thread has a while loop in this style:

```
while(!stop){

    int instruction = InputStream.read();

    switch(instruction){
         ... //processes data here
    }

}
```

At points, I need to stop this thread, and it is vital that this is done quickly because I am calling for it to stop on the UI thread. To stop the thread, I change the variable stop to true, so logically the while loop should finish and the thread should exit.

When I hover my mouse over the read function, eclipse says that it will return -1 if the end of the stream is reached. My problem is that this is not happening. If an instruction is not received from the sensor, the read function stalls until something is received. Shouldn't it return a -1 because the stream is finished?

Because the read() function is stalling, I am unable to stop the thread. I would use thread.stop(); but this is deprecated and unstable so I want to avoid it. I've also tried using InputStream.available() to see if there is anything available before performing a read, but this returns a 0, even when there are bytes available to be read. Has anybody got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read() method you chose will block until it reads a byte. You can cause it to exit by closing the socket or stream. This will cause an exception (which you need to catch). FYI - You should use the other read() method which returns how many bytes read. The simpler read() method you're using will return -1 for a data byte of 0xff and a bad read.

Comment: That one still doesn't work. It just keeps stalling until something has been read.

Comment: It behaves the same way in that it will wait for the requested number of bytes to arrive before returning. The advantage is that it returns the actual number of bytes read. The other function just returns the data. You will still need to close the stream or socket to unblock that call and then handle the exception.